# Excel vba get cell position from array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

[image]

Hi

I want to loop through a source range and pickup the actual cell position from the source array, and apply conditional formating on a destination range, with each cell referencing the unique cell in source range. Plase see the picture for description.

So instead of getting the value in "A2" (for instance "1") from range "A2:C3". Id' like to get the positional excel value of "Sheet1!A2" ..B2 etc.

' High level approach

```
Sub setcondformat()

Dim sourcearr ??, Dim destarr ??, Dim Strpos as String

Dim Strvalue as String ' not necessary, but interesting for educational purposes

For each cell in Source Array do

 select next cell in destination Array    ' eg Sheet2!"J2", "K2" etc ..

  Set conditional format value = Strpos     ' in cond format dialog eg "A2", "B2" etc..

   Next cell sourcearr

end loop


End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you all you are really trying to do is return the address of the cell you are currently on in your For Loop, you can just write something like:

```
For Each cell In SourceArray
    MsgBox cell.Address
Next
```

Obviously you would want to store the address as a variable, or into an array to use the address later. This will return $A$1 if the cell is currently *looping* through cell `A1`. If you were calling the cells value, as mentioned in your questions, you would use `cell.value` to return the actual visible value in the cell.  If this is not what you are after, please let me know and I will attempt to adjust my answer.

Comment: That worked for part of the problem. I tested and yes I can get the cell.address, which is part of what I was looking for.
So the flow would be
0 (outside loop- Select 1 destination cell in destination array.)
1 get cell.address from sourcearray as you suggested.
2 add it to conditional format in the destination cell that is currently selected
3 select next destination cell

So I need to do a nested loop or similar to move to next destination cell to apply the conditional format in cell 2 in the destination array with the reference to cell two in source array.

Comment: Good, that's half the battle then.  Can you try to explain a little more what you want done for your conditional formatting? I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what it is you are trying to do, and which range you are trying to apply conditional formatting to. 

How I am interpreting it is, you want to take the range `(A1:C3)` take those values and place them on a different sheet, and apply a different type of conditional formatting on them? How are you determining the conditional format, and how do you know what is going where?

Comment: Yes, the "problem" is that I have two large range's. One sheet called sheet1(user variables) which has a range of 20*7 cells of values that is going to alter the conditional formats number "rules" in sheet2 (20*7 cells). 
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueFormula
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Value = "=Sheet2!$B$" & i + 3
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 192
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    i = i + 1
Loop
Continues..

Comment: ..continues
So =Sheet2!$B$" & i + 3 needs to be changed to say  = Strpos + 3, and with your suggestion that might work. But I also need to do this on a cell by cell basis. Therefor I need to move to next cell, apply the cell.address in conditional format, move to next cell, apply the cell.address..

Comment: Are these ranges both the same addresses, just a different sheet name? I.e., `Sheet1!A1:A30` and `Sheet2!A1:A30`?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(
I see two options. To set the conditinal formatting as "formulas" meaning they'll udpate live, meaning run the macro once and no more. 
Or get the values, meaning each time enduser updates sheet1, the macro needs to run to pick up values as "numbers" instead in conditional formating, meaning macro needs to run on each update. Run on each update I can solve in option two. But not the nested looping part of this problem

Comment: The problem has been solved. With the help from Busse's suggestion.
I managed to do a nested loop using offsets and iterate through the cells needed. Thanks for your advice Busse, it got me started in the right direction

Comment: @stack_henk, I am glad that such a minor tip could lead you to the correct answer - which leads me to assume that you took what I provided, learned from it, and further expanded your knowledge to lsolve the issue on your own.

I am glad it help! Mark it up/Correct answer if that's the case and congratulations on getting it working!